# Swing JButton same shape as its icon

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to give a JButton the same shape as its icon?

Lets say, this is my button:

```
    JButton infoButton = new JButton(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon"));
```

Is it possible to define, that my button has the same shape as"OptionPane.informationIcon"?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You probably need to create a subclass of `JButton` and override method `contains`. Maybe this example of a [circular button](https://www.javacodex.com/More-Examples/2/14) will help.

Comment: the method to override is paintComponent

Comment: The short "answer" is "yes", BUT, the devil is in the detail and what you want to achieve.  If you're hoping to get it work with the look and feel, then, no, it's probably not going to work.  One idea is to simply turn off the fill and border effects, then you're just going to get the icon ... oh and the focus rectangle